# Can I use the URL Rewrite feature to redirect an entire subfolder using a wildcard?

Tags: url, htaccess

Here's my problem. We switched to Magento from a Volusion site. In our Volusion site we had over 100,000 parts in our database with a url structure  [like this](https://www.mxmegastore.com/product-p/p479755.htm). All of our parts were in the `product-p` folder. I want to redirect everything in that sub folder to our new parts section  [here](http://www.mxmegastore.com/parts-chemicals.html) on our Magento site by using some sort of wildcard like *. I've tried tried in it using the URL rewrite feature as well as trying to manually code this directly into our `.htaccess` file. I've tried everything I can think of and I'm not getting anywhere.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .htaccess with this rule to redirect /product-p/* to base path /

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /product-p/(.*) /$1
```

Note: use 'RewriteEngine On' only if you already enable.

Comment: Thanks. We did end up figuring it out by adding some code to our htaccess file. Below is what we used if anyone is interested.

#RewriteRule ^product-p https://www.examplesite.com/parts-chemicals.html [R]